# Capybara randomly throws validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

In my project I have a lot of common forms (50) which have as different and also common fields from form to form. My task is to iterate through all of forms, fill in all required fields and submit them. But I stuck with a problem - Capybara on a random form after submit button pressed throws an error that shows:

```
Latitude couldn't be determined, maybe patient's or practice's postcodes are invalid?
```

Full error message is here:

```
1) Submit all non-interactive forms Submit all forms
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('Your form has been successfully submitted.')
       expected to find text "Your form has been successfully submitted." in "You are signed in as 'test_postcode (Test Practice) - practice_test_user@test.com' | Sign out Settings View system messages Validation failed: Latitude couldn't be determined, maybe patient's or practice's postcodes are invalid? ← Back To Dashboard Referral An asterisk (*) indicates that a field is mandatory and a referral cannot be submitted without completing. STEP 1: ESSEX ORAL SURGERY TEST FORM * ROUTINE EXTRACTIONS ONLY ACCEPTED WHEN DETAILED JUSTIFICATION IS PROVIDED FOR WHY THIS CANNOT BE DONE IN PRIMARY CARE **PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS FORM SHOULD NOT BE USED FOR SUSPECTED CANCER REFERRALS. NOTE THAT INDICATING SEDATION / GA DOES NOT GUARANTEE PROVISION GENERAL ANAESTHETICS ARE NOT AVAILABLE FOR HEALTHY ADULTS UNDERGOING ROUTINE PROCEDURES. NHS number if known: Sex: M F Title: Mr Mrs Miss Ms Master Dr Patient’s first name: Patient’s last name: Date of birth: Patient's postcode: Patient's address: Patient's town or city: Best contact number: Is the patient exempt? Yes No Referrer’s name: Practice name: Date of decision to refer: Interpreter required Choose language Practice postcode: Practice address: Practice town or city: Practice phone number: GDC number: Care type: Routine Urgent Advice GMP's name: GMP's postcode: GMP's address: GMP's city or town: Patient is not registered with a doctor RADIOGRAPHS MUST BE ATTACHED FOR ALL EXTRACTIONS - PLEASE SUPPLY PA'S OF THIRD MOLARS IF NO ACCESS TO DPT Patient’s principal complaint: Everything You Need to Know About Dental and Oral Health Main reason for referral: Routine extraction of teeth* Removal of simple impacted teeth Surgical endodontics on single rooted anterior teeth Removal of buried / fractured root fragments Difficult extraction Complex impaction Other (e.g. benign oral mucosal lesions such as mucocoele/fibroepithelial polyp or facial pain/TMJ) Please indicate requested anaesthesia (please complete IOSN form if anything other than local) Local anaesthetic only IV Sedation GA If other describe here or use to provide more information: Referral Reason Text For extractions, please indicate below the teeth / roots to be removed: PERMANENT DENTITION 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 PRIMARY DENTITION e d c b a a b c d e e d c b a a b c d e Please describe why specialist care is required? Please describe any previous treatment for the condition referred. For third molars please explain how NICE guidelines are met? Reason for Care Does this patient require bariatric chair provision? Yes No Does this patient’s BMI suggest that they may not be able to receive sedation in primary care? Yes No Next step STEP 2: ADULT MEDICAL HISTORY STEP 3: UPLOAD FILES"
```

I looked at my code and I know that I have postcode validation:

```
validates_presence_of :latitude, :message => "couldn't be determined, maybe postcode is invalid?", if: :geocoding_expected?

def geocoding_expected?
  postcode.present?
end

def geocode
    coordinates = Routing::Geo::Utils.geocode(postcode, geocoding_address)
    self.latitude = coordinates['latitude']
    self.longitude = coordinates['longitude']
  end
```

And here is feature spec code where I fill postcode fields:

```
if page.has_field?('patient_postcode', wait: 0)
      fill_in 'patient_postcode', with: 'BN20 8HR'
end

if page.has_field?('nursery_postcode', wait: 0)
  fill_in 'nursery_postcode', with: 'BN20 8HR'
end
```

But in all of my forms I have required field - postcode, and I fill in this field value from this British site: https://www.doogal.co.uk/PostcodeGenerator.php and I don't know why Capybara throws that validation error.
Help me please!!!

Comment: You're just feeding us tiny pieces of the puzzle here. Like most debugging questions I don't think this question can be answered without a complete example.

Comment: But are you setting the latitude somehow? you say you fill in postcode, and the validation see the postcode is present so it validates the presence of the latitude attribute

Comment: @arieljuod Yes, I added code (geocode method)

Comment: When is that method called? are you sure it's being called? is Routing::Geo::Utils.geocode returning valid values? Are you doing a real http request to that postcode british site? you shouldn't do real http requests on tests.

Comment: @arieljuod Nice question, I know only that it's being called (because I pass a lot of forms on test and on a random form error appears)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test is failing because the page doesn't contain the text you're telling it to expect. The question is why isn't the text matching. From the error you can see that the problem is your model is failing validation in your application.  To figure out why that is happening, look at your `test.log` and see what is actually being POSTed to the application. There's two possibilities there

1. A partial postcode is being submitted - In this case diagnose by adding a short sleep after filling in the postcode, if that fixes the issue it tells you that JS behavior attached to the postcode input is taking longer to process than the time it takes Capybara to go click the submit button. You can leave the sleep to solve the problem but the correct solution is to add an expectation on whatever vchanges on the page to show that the JS behavior attached to the input has completed.
2. The full postcode is being submitted - Then you either have a bug in your application, the postcode you're filling in is invalid, or possibly the address you're setting isn't actually valid for the postcode (last one depends on how specific the Routing::Geo::Utils library you're using is).

Comment: If I change "wait" time (from 0 to 5 for example) the same as if I set sleep time? Locally all forms submit with no errors

Comment: Changed sleep to 10 is the same - error still appears. Log file (test.log) shows not very useful information (I see the same result + something more) https://pastebin.com/L6QeqQir

Comment: @JessieScinor The `test.log` file shows VERY useful information - `Geocode.farm geocoding request for 'BN208HR, UK' failed: {"geocoding_results"=> ...  "STATUS"=>{"access"=>"FREE_USER, ACCESS_GRANTED", "status"=>"FAILED, NO_RESULTS"}` - From that you can tell that Capybara is filling in the full postcode "BN208HR" - and that the problem is that the postcode you're using isn't actually valid for geocoding (or the library/service you're using doesn't know about it) - ie. case 2 from my answer

Comment: Note - you're using a free service to do the geocoding which limits you to 250 checks per day (and 4 per second) which you could easily exceed running tests. You probably want to look into something like https://github.com/vcr/vcr in order to limit the number of actual requests you make out to the real service while running your tests.

Comment: Where did you find this info about number of checks per day and my (free) type of geocoding?

Comment: Oh, found it. Thank you very much for your help. I thought that problem was with my bad test code. God bless you!